# How to get the content of CKeditor using WebDriver

Tags: selenium, ckeditor, webdriver

I'd like to be able to test the content in CKeditor using webdriver.
However there are some hurdles; firstly CKeditor uses Iframes, and there are several Iframes on the page, so not sure how to switch reliably to it using WebDriver as they don't have specific names.

In addition, the content inside the editor is within a `<body></body>` tag inside the iframe.  I'm not sure how to get WebDriver to return the content reliably.

Has anyone actually tried to do this in their tests? If so, how did you achieve it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CKEditor api and execute javascript.  Not sure which selenium driver you are using but here is the java script you can use to get the HTML for:

```
"return CKEDITOR.instances['youreditoridhere'].getData();"
```

Comment: Can this be passed back into my C# NUnit test?

Comment: Of course, it would go smoething like this, don't quote me on it as I don't use selnium in c#: 
    `IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    string title = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return            CKEDITOR.instances['youreditoridhere'].getData();");`

Answer (score 0):

u may refer this
http://bharath-marrivada.blogspot.com/2012/03/fckeditor-switch-activeelement.html

hopes this help ;D